# How to trigger a re-render of a plot when a column content of the plotted data changes with the use of reactive element

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, reactive, r-plotly

In the following app the user can select points in the plot by dragging, which should swap their  `Selected` state between 0 and 1

points will get a shape and color depending on their 0 / 1 state, as a visual support for a user to select/deselect model parameters for the next model run.

in the version of the plots I had in my real app, the plotted data is a reactive variable `values$RFImp_FP1` but I found out that the plot does not re-render when the content of column `Selected` of that data.table (or data.frame)  changes.

Therefore I am trying to change it to a `reactive` object, but I'm failing to figure out how to change the `Selected` column of `reactive` data.table `RFImp

my attempts (comments in the code) so far produce either an assign error, or an infinite loop.

**P.S.:** Since i'm coding the stuff with lapply as I am using the code block several times in my app (identical "modules" with different serial number and using different data as the app takes the user through sequential stages of processing data), the second approach with `values` (app 2) has my preference as this allows me to do things like this:

`lapply(c('FP1', 'FP2'), function(FP){
values[[paste('RFAcc', FP, sep = '_')]] <-` ".... code to select a dataframe from model result list object `values[[paste('RFResults', FP, sep = '_']]$Accuracy`...."
which as far as I know can't be done with `objectname <- reactive({....})` as you can't paste on the left side of the `<-` here

**REACTIVE OBJECT APPROACH:**

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput('RFAcc_FP1',  width = 450)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    if(!is.null(RFImp_FP1()$Selected)) {
      parsToChange <- event_data("plotly_selected", source = 'RFAcc_FP1')$y
      if(!is.null(event_data("plotly_selected", source = 'RFAcc_FP1'))){
        data_df <- RFImp_FP1()
        data_df <- data_df %>% .[, Selected := if_else(Variables %in% parsToChange, 1-Selected, Selected)]
        # how to get the reactive Data frame to update the selected

        # values$Selected <- data_df$Selected    #creates infinite loop.....
        # RFImp_FP1$Selected <- data_df$Selected # throws an error
      }
    }
  })



  RFImp_FP1 <- reactive({ 
    # in real app the dataframe RFImp_FP1 is a part of a list with randomForest results, 
    RFImp_FP1 <- data.table( MeanDecreaseAccuracy =  runif(10, min = 0, max = 1), Variables = letters[1:10])
    RFImp_FP1$Selected <- 1   
    # RFImp_FP1$Selected <- if(!is.null(values$Selected)){
    #  values$Selected } else {1 }

    RFImp_FP1
  })


  output$RFAcc_FP1 <- renderPlotly({
    RFImp_FP1()[order(MeanDecreaseAccuracy)]
    RFImp_score <- RFImp_FP1()
    plotheight <- length(RFImp_score$Variables) * 80
    p <- plot_ly(data = RFImp_score,
                 source = 'RFAcc_FP1',
                 height = plotheight,
                 width = 450)  %>%
      add_trace(x = RFImp_score$MeanDecreaseAccuracy,
                y = RFImp_score$Variables,
                type = 'scatter',
                mode = 'markers',
                color = factor(RFImp_score$Selected),
                colors = c('#1b73c1', '#797979'),
                symbol = factor(RFImp_score$Selected),
                symbols = c('circle','x'),
                marker = list(size  = 6),
                hoverinfo = "text",
                text = ~paste ('<br>', 'Parameter: ', RFImp_score$Variables,
                               '<br>',  'Mean decrease accuracy: ', format(round(RFImp_score$MeanDecreaseAccuracy*100, digits = 2), nsmall = 2),'%',
                               sep = '')) %>%
      layout(
        margin = list(l = 160, r= 20, b = 70, t = 50),
        hoverlabel = list(font=list( color = '#1b73c1'), bgcolor='#f7fbff'),
        xaxis =  list(title = 'Mean decrease accuracy index (%)',
                      tickformat = "%",
                      showgrid = F,
                      showline = T,
                      zeroline = F,
                      nticks = 5,
                      font = list(size = 8),
                      ticks = "outside",
                      ticklen = 5,
                      tickwidth = 2,
                      tickcolor = toRGB("black")
        ),
        yaxis =  list(categoryarray = RFImp_score$Variables,
                      autorange = T,
                      showgrid = F,
                      showline = T,
                      autotick = T,
                      font = list(size = 8),
                      ticks = "outside",
                      ticklen = 5,
                      tickwidth = 2,
                      tickcolor = toRGB("black")
        ),
        dragmode =  "select"
      ) %>%  add_annotations(x = 0.5,
                             y = 1.05,
                             textangle = 0,
                             font = list(size = 14,
                                         color = 'black'),
                             text = "Contribution to accuracy",
                             showarrow = F,
                             xref='paper',
                             yref='paper')

    p <- p %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
    p
  })


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**PREVIOUS reactiveValues() approach:**
as you can see, with this app, the plot does not update when selecting a region in the plot even though the code changes the content of column `Selected`

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = 'Go', label = 'Go'),
  plotlyOutput('RFAcc_FP1',  width = 450)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    if(!is.null(values$RFImp_FP1)) {
      parsToChange <- event_data("plotly_selected", source = 'RFAcc_FP1')$y
      if(!is.null(event_data("plotly_selected", source = 'RFAcc_FP1'))){
        data_df <- values$RFImp_FP1
        data_df <- data_df %>% .[, Selected := if_else(Variables %in% parsToChange, 1-Selected, Selected)]
        values$RFImp_FP1 <- data_df
      }
    }
  })


  observeEvent(input$Go, { 
      values$RFImp_FP1 <- data.table(MeanDecreaseAccuracy =  runif(10, min = 0, max = 1), Variables = letters[1:10])
      values$RFImp_FP1$Selected <- 1
  })


  output$RFAcc_FP1 <- renderPlotly({
    if(!is.null(values$RFImp_FP1)) {

      RFImp_score <- values$RFImp_FP1[order(MeanDecreaseAccuracy)]
      plotheight <- length(RFImp_score$Variables) * input$testme
      p <- plot_ly(data = RFImp_score,
                   source = 'RFAcc_FP1',
                   height = plotheight,
                   width = 450)  %>%
        add_trace(x = RFImp_score$MeanDecreaseAccuracy,
                  y = RFImp_score$Variables,
                  type = 'scatter',
                  mode = 'markers',
                  color = factor(RFImp_score$Selected),
                  colors = c('#1b73c1', '#797979'),
                  symbol = factor(RFImp_score$Selected),
                  symbols = c('circle','x'),
                  marker = list(size  = 6),
                  hoverinfo = "text",
                  text = ~paste ('<br>', 'Parameter: ', RFImp_score$Variables,
                                 '<br>',  'Mean decrease accuracy: ', format(round(RFImp_score$MeanDecreaseAccuracy*100, digits = 2), nsmall = 2),'%',
                                 sep = '')) %>%
        layout(
          margin = list(l = 160, r= 20, b = 70, t = 50),
          hoverlabel = list(font=list( color = '#1b73c1'), bgcolor='#f7fbff'),
          xaxis =  list(title = 'Mean decrease accuracy index (%)',
                        tickformat = "%",
                        showgrid = F,
                        showline = T,
                        zeroline = F,
                        nticks = 5,
                        font = list(size = 8),
                        ticks = "outside",
                        ticklen = 5,
                        tickwidth = 2,
                        tickcolor = toRGB("black")
          ),
          yaxis =  list(categoryarray = RFImp_score$Variables,
                        autorange = T,
                        showgrid = F,
                        showline = T,
                        autotick = T,
                        font = list(size = 8),
                        ticks = "outside",
                        ticklen = 5,
                        tickwidth = 2,
                        tickcolor = toRGB("black")
          ),
          dragmode =  "select"
        ) %>%  add_annotations(x = 0.5,
                               y = 1.05,
                               textangle = 0,
                               font = list(size = 14,
                                           color = 'black'),
                               text = "Contribution to accuracy",
                               showarrow = F,
                               xref='paper',
                               yref='paper')


      p$elementId <- NULL   ## to surpress warning of widgetid
      p <- p %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
      p

    } else {
      p <- plot_ly( type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',  height = '400px', width = 450) %>% layout(
        margin = list(l = 160, r= 20, b = 70, t = 50),
        xaxis = list(title = 'Mean decrease accuracy index', range= c(0,1), nticks = 2, showline = TRUE),
        yaxis = list(title = 'Model input variables', range = c(0,1), nticks = 2, showline = TRUE)) %>%
        add_annotations(x = 0.5, y = 1.1, textangle = 0, font = list(size = 14, color = 'black'),
                        text = 'Contribution to accuracy',
                        showarrow = F, xref='paper', yref='paper')
      p$elementId <- NULL
      p <- p %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
      p}
  })


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want (it´s a bit weird that the plot updates with random numbers after selecting points ;-) ), but I hope it helps.

Instead of using a normal observer I use `observeEvent` that fires when selecting something in the plot. I generally prefer observeEvent to catch an event. This triggers an update ob a `reactiveValues` value, which will initially be `NULL`

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

testDF <- data.table( MeanDecreaseAccuracy =  runif(10, min = 0, max = 1), Variables = letters[1:10])
testDF$Selected <- T

ui <- fluidPage(
    plotlyOutput('RFAcc_FP1',  width = 450)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    values <- reactiveValues(val = NULL)

    observeEvent(event_data("plotly_selected", source = 'RFAcc_FP1')$y, {
        values$val <- runif(1, min = 0, max = 1)
    })


    RFImp_FP1 <- reactive({ 
        RFImp_FP1 <- testDF
        if(!is.null(values$val)) {
            parsToChange <- event_data("plotly_selected", source = 'RFAcc_FP1')$y
            RFImp_FP1 <- RFImp_FP1 %>% .[, Selected := if_else(Variables %in% parsToChange, 1-Selected, Selected)]
        } else { }
        # in real app the dataframe RFImp_FP1 is a part of a list with randomForest results, 
        RFImp_FP1
        # RFImp_FP1$Selected <- if(!is.null(values$Selected)){
        #  values$Selected } else {1 }


    })


    output$RFAcc_FP1 <- renderPlotly({

        RFImp_score <- RFImp_FP1()[order(MeanDecreaseAccuracy)]
        plotheight <- length(RFImp_score$Variables) * 80
        p <- plot_ly(data = RFImp_score,
                     source = 'RFAcc_FP1',
                     height = plotheight,
                     width = 450)  %>%
            add_trace(x = RFImp_score$MeanDecreaseAccuracy,
                      y = RFImp_score$Variables,
                      type = 'scatter',
                      mode = 'markers',
                      color = factor(RFImp_score$Selected),
                      colors = c('#1b73c1', '#797979'),
                      symbol = factor(RFImp_score$Selected),
                      symbols = c('circle','x'),
                      marker = list(size  = 6),
                      hoverinfo = "text",
                      text = ~paste ('<br>', 'Parameter: ', RFImp_score$Variables,
                                     '<br>',  'Mean decrease accuracy: ', format(round(RFImp_score$MeanDecreaseAccuracy*100, digits = 2), nsmall = 2),'%',
                                     sep = '')) %>%
            layout(
                margin = list(l = 160, r= 20, b = 70, t = 50),
                hoverlabel = list(font=list( color = '#1b73c1'), bgcolor='#f7fbff'),
                xaxis =  list(title = 'Mean decrease accuracy index (%)',
                              tickformat = "%",
                              showgrid = F,
                              showline = T,
                              zeroline = F,
                              nticks = 5,
                              font = list(size = 8),
                              ticks = "outside",
                              ticklen = 5,
                              tickwidth = 2,
                              tickcolor = toRGB("black")
                ),
                yaxis =  list(categoryarray = RFImp_score$Variables,
                              autorange = T,
                              showgrid = F,
                              showline = T,
                              autotick = T,
                              font = list(size = 8),
                              ticks = "outside",
                              ticklen = 5,
                              tickwidth = 2,
                              tickcolor = toRGB("black")
                ),
                dragmode =  "select"
            ) %>%  add_annotations(x = 0.5,
                                   y = 1.05,
                                   textangle = 0,
                                   font = list(size = 14,
                                               color = 'black'),
                                   text = "Contribution to accuracy",
                                   showarrow = F,
                                   xref='paper',
                                   yref='paper')

        p <- p %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
        p
    })


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yeah this helped a lot. Still puzzling why this works and not another solution with observeEvent from the other question. 
The reason for the random numbers is because the data.table is remade with random values inside the reactive. making TestDF <-..... outside the app, and then assigning to RFImp_FP1 solves that

Comment: great, always happy about vote or accept :-). Gave you a suggestion for the issue in the other question. Did you see that?

Comment: playing around with it, but even with observeEvent instead of observe, it still does not work correctly

Comment: yes, try to get rid of that workflow => use an eventreactive that listens to the selection. Eventreactive is made for returning data, observers are for there to capture side effects.